# Create Search Field Suggestion Box With Multiple Lines per Entry

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a multiline search field in SAP UI5 similar to the example shown below from the [SAP Fiori Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/search/).

The basic implementation is this with the item and then a description section in italic.

[image]

Further down the page, it seems like to make a 'form' as an item in the complete:

[image]

Has anyone successfully done this type of 'form' implementation in an SAP UI5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of 'form' as an aggregation of sap.m.SearchField is incorrect. In the reference itself they are clearly describing about **refresh button**.

[image]

Which you can avail by below property

[image]

If you are looking for lookalike control then I suggest you to check [Input with key and value tabular suggestions](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputKeyValueTabularSuggestions) example. It has an UI which satisfy your 'form' like structure.

[image]